# No source code is available for type org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.lib.Conversions; did you forget to inherit a required module?

Tags: gwt, xtend

My Xtend/GWT app was working great until I tried to do a forEach on an array.

Now I'm getting

```
No source code is available for type org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.lib.Conversions; did you forget to inherit a required module?
```

Code

```
def transferAttributesToElement(String... attributeNames) {
    attributeNames.forEach [
        element.setAttribute(it, attributeMap.get(it)?.toString())
    ]
}
```

Xbase entry in pom

```
<dependencies>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.xtext</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.lib.gwt</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.2</version>
  </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Inherit in gwt.xml

```
<inherits name='org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.lib.Lib'/>
```

Xtend source compatibility level `Java 7`

`Java 7` on classpath

**EDIT**

Java source generated by Xtend for the above snippet

```
final Procedure1<String> _function = new Procedure1<String>() {
  @Override
  public void apply(final String it) {
    Object _get = HtmlBuilderBase.this.attributeMap.get(it);
    String _string = null;
    if (_get!=null) {
      _string=_get.toString();
    }
    HtmlBuilderBase.this.element.setAttribute(it, _string);
  }
};
IterableExtensions.<String>forEach(((Iterable<String>)Conversions.doWrapArray(attributeNames)), _function);
```

Comment: Where does Conversions appear exactly in your code?

Comment: @zakariaamine Updated question to add java source generated by my posted Xtend code, which contains the reference to Conversions.